# Convert string with bad format to date type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to convert this kind of string to date type in Typescript for sorting purpose:

```
31/10/2017 18:12:02
```

new Date() is not working (I get Invalid Date), even like this :

```
let date = moment(item1.sendedOn.toString()).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss');
console.log(date.toString());
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert this to ISO Format and then use `new Date()`

```js
var dateStr = "2018-12-23 18:12:02".replace(" ", "T") + ".000Z";

console.log(new Date(dateStr).getTime());
// Use sorting on this now as it is directly comparable
```

**Update** (If you have a `/` as a date separator):

```js
var dateStr = "2018-12-23 18:12:02".replace(/\//g, "-").replace(" ", "T") + ".000Z";

console.log(new Date(dateStr).getTime());
```

Comment: I updated the date format in the question. That was not the good one. If you could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

> new Date() is not working (I get Invalid Date)

Perhaps the string you have shown is not the actual string that you are having issues with or there are hidden characters like spaces. As you can see in the script included in this answer that your string (from your question) does not throw an exception/error when passed to the `Date` constructor.

```js
var result = new Date('2018-12-23 18:12:02');
console.log(result);
```

*If this script does not work on your browser maybe it is a browser specific issue*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to achieve the same.

```js
var date = moment("2018-12-23 18:12:02").format('DD-MM-YYYY');
console.log(date)
var dateObj = moment("2018-12-23 18:12:02").toDate();
console.log(dateObj)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to use it with typescript and angular2

```
npm install moment --save

import * as moment from 'moment';

providers: [{ provide: 'moment', useValue: moment }]
```

Comment: Amazing.. Is a String, operator <= or operator >= (as your format date is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, you have no problem, other case is if you use a format dd-mm-yyyy or 12 hour time

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with moment.js :

```
 let date = moment(stringDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss').format();
```